# Unable to set value based on INSERTED table in trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, triggers

**GOAL**:I'm creating after insert trigger that should insert new record to OrderSuspendRule table based on rule in this table that was related with Promotion of which new version was created.

**PROBLEM**
I cannot set value to @SUS_ID. Select returns value but it isn't set to variable.

Sample insert:

```
INSERT INTO PromotionHeader (Guid,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,IsActive,CompanyId,UpdatedById,CreatedById,Name,[Description],ValidFrom,ValidTo,BusinessUnitId,OfferId,[Version],StatusId,PreviousId)
select newid(),CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,1,CompanyId,UpdatedById,CreatedById,Name,[Description],ValidFrom,ValidTo,BusinessUnitId,OfferId,[Version]+1,StatusId,916 FROM PromotionHeader WHERE Id=916
```

Where PreviousId points to older version of promotion.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRIG1 ON DBO.PromotionHeader
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @SUS_ID INT

SET @SUS_ID = (
        SELECT Max(id)
        FROM OrderSuspendRule
        WHERE PromotionHeaderId = (
        SELECT PreviousId
        FROM inserted
                WHERE ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
                )
                AND ISACTIVE=1
        )

IF (@SUS_ID IS NOT NULL) --**VARIABLE IS ALWAYS NULL NO MATTER WHAT**
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO OrderSuspendRule (
        Guid
        ,CreatedAt
        ,UpdatedAt
        ,IsActive
        ,CompanyId
        ,UpdatedById
        ,CreatedById
        ,SuspendFrom
        ,SuspendTo
        ,PromotionHeaderId
        ,SuspendTypeId
        ,OfferItemId
        )
    SELECT NEWID()
        ,GETDATE()
        ,GETDATE()
        ,1
        ,CompanyId
        ,UpdatedById
        ,CreatedById
        ,SuspendFrom
        ,SuspendTo
        ,SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        ,SuspendTypeId
        ,OfferItemId
    FROM OrderSuspendRule
    WHERE id = @SUS_ID
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a `for insert` trigger, you can assume that all rows in the `inserted` table were inserted.  There is no need to double check this with `scope_identity()`.

To explain why `scope_identity()` is `null`, remember that `scope_identity()` returns the last inserted identity in the current scope.  Since your trigger runs in its own scope, this will always be `null`, unless the trigger itself performs an insert.

Also, be aware that your trigger can be run for an insert of multiple rows.  That means you can't expect only a single `@sus_id`, there might be many.

Comment: Thanks, I was checking scope_identity() and it was returning values but I didn't think about that trigger runs in different scope. Also I took into account fact of multiple row insert by using cursor. Thanks again!